# TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable for res object type

Tags: python, image, nonetype, gridfs

```
# ROW 4
start_date = DateEntry(start_frame, selectmode='day', year=2020, month=11, day=22)
start_date.grid(row=4, column=0, sticky=W, padx=10, pady=10)

end_date = DateEntry(start_frame, selectmode='day', year=2020, month=11, day=22)
end_date.grid(row=4, column=1, sticky=W, padx=10, pady=10)
```

> I keep gettin the erorr for Nonetype, what am i doing wrong? the
> databse connected is mongoDB for GridFS below for res object

```
 res = (test.find_one({"_id": 1}))['models']
    clicked.set(res[0])
```

> ```
> res = (test.find_one({"_id": 1}))['models'] TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
> ```

```
drop = OptionMenu(start_frame, clicked, *res)
drop.grid(row=4, column=2, sticky=W, padx=10, pady=10)
```

Comment: You haven't said what's in `test`, but the error suggests that `(test.find_one({"_id": 1}))` is None at least some of the time. I'd guess you're probably not finding anything that matches the given _id value, and find_one() returns None in that situation.

Comment: yes test is the database where i am storing images using gridfs. how can i rectify this error then?. i even tried removing the ID matching: res = (test.find_one())['models']. still getting the same error